# add class to each 3th and 4th div block for grid using php

Tags: php, loops

hi im making a grid with divs like so:

```
        <div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green;margin-right:10px;">

        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green;margin-right:10px;">

        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green">

        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green;margin-left:10px;">

        </div>
```

now because of design issues the 3rth doesnt have a right marign but the 4th has a left margin

so i want a method in php that i can pass a count to an return a class a (for 3th and b for 4th) iteration

but i dont know what the best way was to do this... I could thing about a counter and then if x/4 is the same as iteration (pass trough) then i can catch the 4rth and then the same for the 3rth but there must be a more simpeler way to do this

Comment: Why not just use CSS's `nth-child`?

Comment: beacuase i need it to work up to ie7....... yes.... dont ask me why

Comment: `$counter%3 == 0` and `$counter%4 == 0` ?

Comment: Indeed, best option is to use the modulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. This is do what you explained:

`%` operator tells you, if there is a division by the given number, how many is the remainder.

```
$third = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    if ($i != 1 && $i % 4 === 0) {
        echo '<div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green;margin-left:10px;">Margined left ' . $i . '</div>' . "\n";
    } elseif ($i !== 1 && $third % 3 == 0) {
        if ($third === 3) {
            $third = -1;
        }
        echo '<div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green;">Not margiend ' . $i . '</div>' . "\n";
    } else {
        echo '<div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green;margin-right:10px;">Margined rigth ' . $i . '</div>' . "\n";
    }
    $third++;
}
```

Comment: so i have to define a total ? like 20 ? or could i also just pas in the total count

Comment: 20 is just for demonstration. There should be any number what you want.

Comment: for some reason it does not work verry well.. just the first row seems fine http://postimg.org/image/p8xpfb973/

Comment: Yes, i see. This is becuase $i%2 works on 4 and every even number, wait and i'll fix.

Comment: Fixed the code, now it works. The problem was the $i%3, because that is true for 3,6,9,12.... while it need to be true on 3,7,11,15,18. So i need to add a counter, what counts, wich is the 3rd element in the block.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. You can always replace the **for** with **foreach** if you are looping throught stuff

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i <= 6; $i++) :?>
    <div style="float:left;width:171px;height:115px;background:green; <?php if($i%3 != 0){ echo "margin-right:10px;"; } ?>">
        test
    </div>  
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: yes.. i was reading about the modulus but i dont really understand the math behind it

Comment: Modulus will return the remainder when two number are dived.
So 9 % 4 = 1 because 4 goes into 9 2 times and leaves a remainder of 1.

So 1 % 2 = 1, 3 % 3 = 0

Comment: It's not handling the 3rd row ($i%2). Please fix that.

Comment: What do you mean third row. Also the answer uses $i%3 not $i%2.